# Decrypt AES 128 encrypted file with a key file

Tags: encryption, decryption, aes

I have a file which is encrypted using AES 128 and I have a key file. How can I decrypt the file using the key file?

The key file has no extension, I opened it in notepad and it has bizarre text.

Comment: Do you know the cipher mode that was used (CBC, GCM, CTR...)? Do you know whether it was encrypted using something like `openssl enc`? How large is the key file in bytes?

Comment: It's a ts file so I think its CBC, I don't know what was used to encrypt, its 61.8 KB

Comment: Also which operating system?

Comment: I don't know which OS was used to encrypt, I am using Windows 10, but can switch to Linux.

Comment: Try opening it with 7-Zip, even though it does not have an extension. 7-Zip is fairly good at recognizing standard file formats, and should open a password dialog if it's recognized.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik 7-Zip gave error stating cannot open file.